# wsdl generator for java code

Tags: wsdl

Can someone please recommend me a good tool to generate wsdl from java code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For JAX-WS, read this post [JAX-WS's wsgen tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666714/generate-wsdl-from-java-class-source).

Most of the open source frameworks provide this feature. Below are two

1. [Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/eclipse/wsdl2java-plugin.html)
2. [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/java-to-wsdl.html)