# Can the WSDL be obtained at build/compile time in a Java project?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, jax-ws

Alternatively:

Is it possible to write the WSDL to a file without deploying to a server?

I would like to generate a WS client from this WSDL before deploying the application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate WSDL from java class\source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666714).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [wsgen](http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2/docs/wsgen.html) to generate the wsdl.

From the example in the documentation

```
wsgen -wsdl -d stock -cp myclasspath stock.StockService
```

This will generate the wsdl and schema files in the "stock" directory.

There is also a [wsgen Ant task](http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2/docs/wsgenant.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Maven, you can use plugins as [jaxws-maven-plugin](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/) or [maven-jaxb2-plugin](http://java.net/projects/maven-jaxb2-plugin/pages/Home) for building WS artifacts at build/compile time.