# is there any tool to create a wsdl?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I am new to webServices. I want to develop a webservice in Java. So far I came to know, WSDL is needed to kickstart with WebServices. So, How do I create a WSDL? Is there any  tool which makes this easy?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: usually you don't start with writing the wsdl. you write the web service and the wsdl ist generated automatically for you, or you have a wsdl you can import to implement a ws client.

Comment: Did you try searching with this very string "is there any tool to create a wsdl" ?

Comment: see this post  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666714/generate-wsdl-from-java-class-source

Comment: @santosh: yes. I did search. But since I was of opinion that WSDL is the starting point for creating web service, they didnt make much sense to me. Now they do.

Comment: @kaushikv WS has two two approaches, Contract-first wherein you need wsdl beforehand and Contract-last wherein you arrive at wsdl as a last step in your web services deployment.

Comment: @santosh: Thank you. Others have told about generating WSDL from the webservice. I am more interested in starting from WSDL. So, any pointers to kick start?

Comment: I don't know which web services stack you are using here in example from  [spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/why-contract-first.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use JAX-WS (ships with Java 6, separate download for Java 5) and you expose a @WebMethod properly the WSDL can be automatically generated by the JAX-WS stack at runtime.