# How to get WSDL file from for an outbound web service

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

Could anyone please help me in understanding hoe to generate wsdl file for outbound web service?

I have an outbound web service in my application. I have to get the WSDL file with endpoint tag, need to share with the client who consumes the web service

Thanks
Arun

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking about the wsgen tool, assuming you are using JAX-WS. [Generate WSDL from java class\source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666714/generate-wsdl-from-java-class-source)